# Unable to login with a specific user in FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

It always worked before, but it is no longer working.

I have a rate limiting logic, but even if I clear all rate limiting data, it still happens. Only with a specific user.

I created another account on FaunaDB for testing purposes and a new database. If I restore the old database data to that new database, everything works!

So I recreated the entire database on the old FaunaDB account and the problem persists.

Is anyone experiencing something similar?
Is there any information in cache?

```js
Login(Match(Index("accounts_by_email"), "email@email.com"), {
  password: "secret",
})

/* returns
Error: [
  {
    "position": [],
    "code": "authentication failed",
    "description": "The document was not found or provided password was incorrect."
  }
]
*/
```

The password is not incorrect. It works on the other FaunaDB account with the data restored.

```sh
./fdm -source path=backup -dest key={admin_key}
```

Comment: Just solved the problem myself. I removed the rate limiting option, because it somehow isn't working. I think that when I remove the record from the database, it still remains in the cache. But I can't prove it. Just an assumption. Next time, I I'll try again with the TTL option set to one day.

Comment: I think this was a temporary problem we had at a certain moment. I can't be sure what caused it though without seeing the code.

Comment: Hi @BrechtDeRooms, thank you for feedback. The code I'm making use was taken from the fwitter repo here: https://github.com/fauna-brecht/fwitter/blob/b1de000f5886e9ea1816a72064161314932ece2b/src/fauna/queries/rate-limiting.js#L74. Of course, I made some minor changes, but the logic in general is pretty much the same. I think it was a temporary thing, like you said, but I still haven't had the chance to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that was a temporary problem. I experienced it was well at a certain moment in my own Fwitter example. Our uniqueness detection didn't play well with code that created/updated/deleted things in one complex FQL flow which the code is doing :). I ticketed that and it should be fixed in the meantime.

It's good to know that the rate limiting in there was a bit me experimenting with events. It can also be written much simpler, I guess I was a bit to deep zoned and to be fair.. I just joined FaunaDB back then. I'm working on a skeleton app that will contain that simpler version. In the meantime here is the code:

**Simpler rate limiting**

```js
import { rateLimiting } from '../../fauna-queries/helpers/errors'
import faunadb from 'faunadb'
/*
 * Ideally we limit the amount of calls that come to Login.
 */
const q = faunadb.query
const {
  If,
  Epoch,
  Match,
  Index,
  Collection,
  Let,
  Var,
  Paginate,
  Select,
  TimeDiff,
  Or,
  GTE,
  Abort,
  Create,
  IsEmpty,
  Count,
  LT,
  Do,
  Now,
  Subtract
} = q

function AddRateLimiting(action, FqlQueryToExecute, Identifier, calls, perMilliseconds) {
  const ExecuteAndCreateLog = Do(
    Create(Collection('logs'), {
      data: {
        action: action,
        identity: Identifier
      }
    }),
    FqlQueryToExecute
  )

  return Let(
    {
      logsPage: Paginate(Match(Index('logs_by_action_and_identity_ordered_by_ts'), action, Identifier), {
        size: calls
      })
    },
    If(
      Or(IsEmpty(Var('logsPage')), LT(Count(Select(['data'], Var('logsPage'))), calls)),
      // If no logs exist yet, create one.
      ExecuteAndCreateLog,
      Let(
        {
          // the page looks like { data: [timestamp1, timestamp2,...]},
          // we will retrieve the last timestamp of that page. If the pagesize would be 3, it would be the oldest of these 3 events.
          // since the index is ordered from new to old.
          timestamp: Select(['data', Subtract(calls, 1)], Var('logsPage')),
          // transform the Fauna timestamp to a Time object
          time: Epoch(Var('timestamp'), 'microseconds'),
          // How long ago was that event in ms
          ageInMs: TimeDiff(Var('time'), Now(), 'milliseconds')
        },
        If(
          GTE(Var('ageInMs'), perMilliseconds),
          // Then great we execute
          ExecuteAndCreateLog,
          // Else.. Abort! Rate-limiting in action
          Abort(rateLimiting)
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

**Blocking after faulty logins**
I also separated blocking three faulty logins since I was kinda **abusing** that rate-limiting system for it. A few undefines in this code of course, it's just meant to give you an idea of how it looks for more info, keep an eye out for the skeletons + blogs to come out.

```js
  // Let's wrap some other functionality around the login.
  const BlockThreeFaultyLogins = Do(
    If(
      GTE(Count(Match(Index('logs_by_action_and_identity'), 'faulty_login', email)), MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS),
      // Abort if exceeded
      Abort(tooManyFaultyLogins),
      // Else, just continue as usual!
      Let(
        {
          login: LoginFQL
        },
        Do(
          If(
            Equals(false, Var('login')),
            // if the login is faulty, we'll add a log entry
            Create(Collection('logs'), {
              data: {
                action: 'faulty_login',
                identity: email
              }
            }),
            // Else, we will clean up the faulty_login logs
            q.Map(
              Paginate(Match(Index('logs_by_action_and_identity'), 'faulty_login', email)),
              Lambda(['logRef'], Delete(Var('logRef')))
            )
          ),
          Var('login')
        )
      )
    )
  )
```